Keeping a snake as a pet is haram or not?
Assalamualaikum
I want to know if I keep pet an animal such as snake , lion , tiger (( but them all are harmless and non poisonous )) is it haram or halal to have it??

It is commanded to kill a snake, keeping one as a pet is contrary to that. A lion or tiger as a house pet is dangerous and illegal in many places, there are numerous tragic incidents where they eventually end up killing or injuring their owner or other people.
